# Class App\Http\Request\CreatePost does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5

this CreatePost.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreatePost extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|string',
            'content' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

anyone please help me ?? Class App\Http\Request\CreatePost does not exist 
thank

Comment: `Requests` in your namespace, `Request` in your error. Make sure the namespace matches in all spots.

Comment: yes work its now thank

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the model on top
for example

```php
use App\Supplier;
```